# Data stream with confluent-kafka python giving error - TypeError: You must pass either str or Schema

Tags: python, apache-kafka, data-ingestion, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to build Stream-Table Join Operations in Kafka python and below is the code that performs join operation on data sent from producer

stream_table_join.py

```
from confluent_kafka import DeserializingConsumer, SerializingProducer 
from confluent_kafka.serialization import StringDeserializer, StringSerializer 
from confluent_kafka import Consumer 
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.json_schema import JSONDeserializer 
import json


class LookupData:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

# Kafka configuration
bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'
events_topic = 'events_topic'

# Configure the Kafka consumer and producer
consumer = DeserializingConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
    'key.deserializer': StringDeserializer(),
    'value.deserializer': JSONDeserializer(LookupData, from_dict=lambda x: LookupData(x['id'], x['name'])),
    'group.id': 'stream-table-join-group'
})
consumer.subscribe([events_topic])

producer = SerializingProducer({
    'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
    'key.serializer': StringSerializer(),
    'value.serializer': StringSerializer()
})

# Load the lookup data from the lookup table
lookup_table = {}

# Join operation function
def join_operation(event):
    """ Join Operation here """


# Start consuming and producing messages
while True:
    event = json.loads(msg.value())
    enriched_event = join_operation(event)
    producer.produce(events_topic, value=json.dumps(enriched_event))
    producer.flush()

consumer.close()
```

There exists a part as shared below

`'value.deserializer': JSONDeserializer(LookupData, from_dict=lambda x: LookupData(x['id'], x['name'])),`

That taps into the data object sent from producer and converts into the
`LookupData`  class object with the help of `JSONDeserializer` , this is done so that additional field can be joined, but everytime the code file is executed, it just shows the error

```
TypeError: You must pass either str or Schema
```

I tried running it both times 1. with Producer running and 2. without producer running, both times I am having the same error and there is not enough explanation on what exactly the error is about or how to solve this

Below is the sample data that is coming from `producer.py`

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
}
```

I tried running the code with producer and without the producer running, both times I received the same error, even checked the documentation and tried to find solutions for the error but found none

Answer (score 0):

```py
from confluent_kafka import DeserializingConsumer
import confluent_kafka
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from configparser import ConfigParser
import json
import fastavro
from io import BytesIO
import logging

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Starting consumer...')

# Read the variables 
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('client.properties')

# Schema registry client
schema_registry_conf = {
  'url': config.get('DEFAULT', 'schema.registry.url'),
  'basic.auth.user.info': config.get('DEFAULT', 'basic.auth.user.info')
}

schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_conf)

# Get the latest version of the value schema
subject_name = "flights-value"
schema = schema_registry_client.get_latest_version(subject_name)
schema_str = schema.schema.schema_str

logging.info(f"Schema String: {schema_str}")  # Add this line to print the schema string

# Convert the schema string to a dictionary
schema_dict = json.loads(schema_str)
logging.info(f'Schema dict: {schema_dict}')
schema_str2= json.dumps(schema_dict)
logging.info(f'Schema_str: {schema_str2}')

def value_deserializer(data, ctx):
    if data is None:
        return None
    try:
        return fastavro.schemaless_reader(BytesIO(data), schema_dict)
    except IndexError as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to deserialize data: {data}")
        logging.error(f"Error: {e}")
        return None
    
def key_deserializer(key, ctx):
    return str(key)

# Configure the consumer
consumer_conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': config.get('DEFAULT', 'bootstrap.servers'),
    'security.protocol': config.get('DEFAULT', 'security.protocol'),
    'sasl.mechanisms': config.get('DEFAULT', 'sasl.mechanisms'),
    'sasl.username': config.get('DEFAULT', 'sasl.username'),
    'sasl.password': config.get('DEFAULT', 'sasl.password'),
    'group.id': 'flight_data_group',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
    'key.deserializer': key_deserializer,
    'value.deserializer': value_deserializer
}

consumer = DeserializingConsumer(consumer_conf)

# Subscribe to the topic
consumer.subscribe(['flights'])

try:
    while True:
        # Poll for messages
        msg = consumer.poll(1.0)

        if msg is None:
            continue

        if msg.error():
            if msg.error().code() == confluent_kafka.KafkaError._VALUE_DESERIALIZATION:
                logging.error(f"Failed to deserialize message value: {msg.error()}")
                continue
            else:
                logging.error(f"Consumer error: {msg.error()}")
                continue

        logging.info(f"Received message: {msg.key()} : {msg.value()} at offset {msg.offset()}")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    # Close down consumer to commit final offsets.
    consumer.close()
```

It work for me, if can help You